How do I get python to stop skipping my for loop?
I have a .txt file containing many customers' details, dates of birth, and addresses. I instructed Python to access this file and ask for my input to search for particular birth years or zip codes.
I called the function inside the function so that it would ask for my input when it completes each search.
The code works on the first try
However the issue is after one search, it skips the 'for' loop and always returns ' match not found' even when my input exists in the file
file = input("Enter file name: ")
custlist= open(file)

#define our function to search for component
def search():
    searchword = input()
    result = None
    for line in custlist :
        cust = line.rstrip()
        if searchword in cust:
            result = line
            print(result)
    if result is None :
        print('match not found')
        search()
search()  


custlist is not a list, it's an open file object. Open file objects are iterators, not collections; once a line is consumed, it's gone, you can't restart a new loop except by seeking back to the beginning.
You need to either:

Change custlist= open(file) to custlist= list(open(file)) (to cache the file lines once and reuse them, and also make custlist a sensible name). Note that this is a bad idea if the file may be large (because you need memory proportionate to file size) but does mean the code is likely to execute faster if the file is small enough. Or
Add custlist.seek(0) just before you begin iterating each time, or
Open the file within the function (with a with statement to ensure it's reliably closed) so you open it once per loop without needing to seek.

I'd also strongly recommend not making your function recursive, and just put it in an infinite loop with a conditional break. As is, it's inherently limited in how many times it can run (you keep building new stack frames, and Python will refuse to go deeper after 1000 frames by default).

list(open(file)) is normally done using open(file).readlines()

@Barmar: I refuse to acknowledge the existence of .readlines() for one reason: It's a trap for people who don't know files are iterables of their lines already, and end up creating lists of their lines when they don't need them (could just iterate directly once), simply because it's easier to find .readlines in the docs than to understand how file objects work naturally. If I were BDFL, .readlines() would have died alongside .xreadlines() in the transition to Python 3. It's ever-so-slighty faster than list(file), but teaches bad habits. steps off soapbox

I teach a Python class for new programmers where even though the class itself specifically says, in its only reference to .readlines, that it is unnecessary 99% of the time, just loop over the file when you need to (it greatly privileges for line in file: in the examples and other uses), I still get half my project submissions with the for line in file.readlines(): anti-pattern, and it drives me nuts.

yeah, we really shouldn't be teaching students to reify the lines in the first place, so both file.readlines() and list(file) should be avoided. Seeking or reopening the file is the right way to go through the file multiple times.

@Barmar: Yep. In this case, if the files are small enough, and they need to be searched repeatedly, caching the lines can make sense. I chose list(file) specifically because it makes it fit into the general pattern, converting iterables to lists (which reminds you file is an iterable already), rather than using a special-purpose API that hides that information. Admittedly, in this case, the OP knows they can iterate a file directly, but still, .readlines() will always be dead to me. Yes, I know I'm a little nuts on this topic.

Are you also against readlines(hint)?

@nocomment: If you use the hint, yeah, it has a benefit, and I'd be okay with that use. I have literally never seen any code that uses the hint. It's the 0.001% use case. That could be done without .readlines(), but it's not clean, so that's the one case I'd be okay with it, if it didn't have a name that lures programmers like a moth to a flame.
